# how to convert a list of nx3 matrices into a list of spatial patterns

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I have a list containing n x 3 matrices. WHere the first column are the X-Coords, the second column is the Y- Coords and the third column is a value ( 1's and 0's). how do iterate through this list to output a list of spatial patterns.

I have tried converting it straight using as.ppp  and a generic rectangular window. However, the output is infinite points, instead of just the locations of 1's

Here is an example of one the matrices in the list:
    x-coord y-coord value
    [1,]   1 301     0
    [2,]   1 302     0
    [3,]   2 302     1
    [4,]   1 303     0
    [5,]   2 303     0
    [6,]   3 303     0
    [7,]   1 304     0
    [8,]   2 304     0
    [9,]   3 304     0

````
enter code here
```r
ww <- owin(c(0,640), c(0,640))
x=lapply(matrix,function(matrix) {as.ppp(matrix,ww)})
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to subset the matrix to only retain the rows where the third column is 1. I assume the first variable you call `matrix` is a list of matrices. I will call it `matrixlist` below. If a single n by 3 matrix is called `m` you find the rows where column 3 is 1 with `m[,3]==1`. Afterwards you only need to keep columns 1 and 2. This all adds up to:

```
x = lapply(matrixlist, function(m) {as.ppp(m[m[,3]==1, 1:2], ww)})
```